# Exclude array alignment in php-cs-fixer Netbeans 8.x

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, php-cs-fixer

I am using `php-cs-fixer` with `Netbeans 8.2`. It is working perfectly except for one case. My arrays are formatted like below

```
$array = [
    'asdf' => 'a',
    'a'    => 'b',
    'asd'  => 'c'
];
```

But after fixing with `php-cs-fixer`, they all changed to

```
$array = [
    'asdf' => 'a',
    'a' => 'b',
    'asd' => 'c'
];
```

**Is there any way to ignore this section only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any way to ignore this section only?*

No, there is no way. See the response to PHP-CS-Fixer issue [#3846: How to ignore specific lines?](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3846)

> **This is a design decision that you shall not allow for exceptions per
>   block of code.** It may or may not be introduced in the future, depends
>   on amount of ppl requesting it and one who would take a challenge to
>   implement it.
>
> Currently, if you are really in need, you can disable file from being
>   fixed at all. But that would mean it would not be fixed by any other
>   rules as well.

So I guess you can update that existing issue to add your voice, and hope that they listen.

Alternatively, you could raise a new issue requesting that there is a new rule in PHP-CS-Fixer which preserves whitespace when formatting arrays. Your formatting certainly looks better than that of PHP-CS-Fixer to me.

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep the alignments after the double arrow ('=>') in associative arrays (old rule `align_double_arrow`), with versions v2 or v3 of PHP-CS-Fixer you need to run:

```
php-cs-fixer fix path \
--rules='{"binary_operator_spaces": {"operators": {"=>": "align_single_space_minimal"}}}'
```

You can do it as well for any binary operator:

```
php-cs-fixer fix path \
--rules='{"binary_operator_spaces": {"default": "align_single_space_minimal"}}'
```

More to read:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/3.0/doc/rules/operator/binary_operator_spaces.rst